# Adapting clustering to partial clutering

Tags: clustering

This is a question primarily about re-appropriating existing clustering methods to work when only a fraction of datapoints are likely to originate from a cluster (as opposed to a global background distribution).

I have a set of high-throughput biological measurements (~400 samples, ~12000 features) and I'm interested in clustering the *features* (so transpose the data matrix). I'm interested in identifying which groups features are under biological constraint, i.e. those that cluster together. The features will be a mixture of groups which are subject to constraints (such as the availability of a rate-limiting compound), and those whose measurements are dominated purely by noise. Furthermore, the scale of the measurements are effectively meaningless, so analyzing ratios relative to a standard, or correlations, is preferred.

I have applied standard clustering algorithms using covariance (and kernels applied to covariance) as a similarity metric, but one potential drawback is that clustering methods they seek to assign every point to a cluster. I expect ~50% of my features to be effectively unrelated to any cluster. Are there good (meaning published and tested on data) post-hoc methods for identifying likely *unclustered* points, removing (or flagging) them, and re-clustering?

As a more general question, are there clustering methods whose optimization problem is particularly amenable for adaptation to such a case?